# Ionic fab button animation issue

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im using Ionic-3 for my mobile application, I tried added this [example](https://codepen.io/seansean11/pen/dhwzj) button and animation is working fine,  but `box shadow` does not work. how can i fix this issue

This is my code 
**css**

```
ion-fab[bottom] {
  bottom: 94px;
}
.fab-md-danger {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #488aff;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, .5);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}
.fab-md-danger.activated {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #a7c6fd;
}


@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    @include transform(scale(.9));
  }
  70% {
    @include transform(scale(1));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
  100% {
    @include transform(scale(.9));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<ion-fab right bottom>
  <button ion-fab color="danger" >
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>

  </button>
</ion-fab>
```

my example https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lenkie?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss

Comment: Please re-produce your problem at https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @Duannx sir look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lenkie?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all `@include transform(...)`. Because you are importing an undefinded function (`transform`).

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse { 
  70% { 
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
  100% { 
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the differences?

Comment: Sir, my mobile application is does not work box shadow animation like as https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lenkie?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss

Comment: i saw you did not remove it

Comment: sorry its not save, this one is workhttps://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lenkie?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss , but im include this for my application its not work

Comment: It works in stackblitz but it does not work in your project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164736/discussion-between-core114-and-duannx).